# mysql 5.7 -e option get error at line 1: unknown command '\u'

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-python

This is the code I wrote on command line:

```
 mysql --user=root --password=root mydb --default-character-set=utf8 -e "set @arg1='[1002,2003,3304]';source run.sql"
```

However, it throws me this error:

> ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\U'

I have tested if I remove set statement like this and run:

```
mysql --user=root --password=root mydb --default-character-set=utf8 -e "source run.sql"
```

The run script file executes.I know I can open the SQL file and change the source code to void this, but this problem is really annoying.

Could anyone have any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Would you please mark the correct answer (here or your other two) with the Green checkmark as Accepted if you agree. That is how we roll here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `;` at the end:

```sql
... -e "set @arg1='[1002,2003,3304]';source run.sql;"
```

or change `source` by `\.`:

```sql
... -e "set @arg1='[1002,2003,3304]';\. run.sql"
```